How do I ingest data from singstat into an S3 bucket using AWS Lambda?
this is the code that i have been using:
import json
import urllib.request
import boto3
import os
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Define the SingStat API 
    endpointapi_url = "https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/tabledata/M651351"

try:
    # Make an HTTP request to the API
    with urllib.request.urlopen(api_url) as response:
        data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
    
    # Process the data as needed
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    
    # Generate a unique filename using the current timestamp
    timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ')
    key = f'daec-project/singstat_data_{timestamp}.json'
    
    # Upload the data to an S3 bucket
    bucket_name = "daec-project"
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Body=json_data, ContentType='application/json')
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Data uploaded to S3 successfully!')
    }

except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    return {
        'statusCode': e.code,
        'body': json.dumps(f'HTTP Error: {e.reason}')
    }

except Exception as e:
    return {
        'statusCode': 500,
        'body': json.dumps(f'Error: {str(e)}')
    }

But AWS Lambda keeps giving me this error:
Test Event Namedaec-proj

Response{"statusCode": 403,"body": ""HTTP Error: Forbidden""}

Function LogsSTART RequestId: 999af3a7-b3d7-4400-940f-a2114e3fccbe Version: $LATESTEND RequestId: 999af3a7-b3d7-4400-940f-a2114e3fccbeREPORT RequestId: 999af3a7-b3d7-4400-940f-a2114e3fccbe    Duration: 1924.69 ms    Billed Duration: 1925 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB  Init Duration: 285.07 ms

Request ID999af3a7-b3d7-4400-940f-a2114e3fccbe


That endpoint apparently requires a user agent and an accept header
